# SuiteScript 2.1 - Invalid Signature when creating TBA Access Token

Tags: oauth, suitescript2.0

Constantly getting `Invalid Signature` when trying to create a TBA access token.

The function to generate the OAuth1.0a signature is as follows:

```
const restletSignature = (options) => {
            
            const HMAC_SHA256 = (key, text, output) => {
                if ( !output) output = cryptoJS.enc.Base64;
                return cryptoJS.HmacSHA256(text, key).toString(output);
            };
            
            const companyInfo = config.load({
                type: config.Type.COMPANY_INFORMATION,
            });
            
            const makeNonce = () => {
                var result = "", characters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
                var charactersLength = characters.length;
                for (var i = 0; i < this.nonce_length; i++) {
                    result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
                }
                return result;
            };
            
            try {
                
                log.debug('options', JSON.stringify(options));
                
                if ( !options) {
                    options = {};
                }
                
                if ( !options.consumer) {
                    throw error.create({
                        name: 'MISSING_PARAMTER',
                        message: 'consumer option is required',
                        notifyOff: true,
                    });
                }
                if ( !options.token) {
                    throw error.create({
                        name: 'MISSING_PARAMTER',
                        message: 'token option is required',
                        notifyOff: true,
                    });
                }
                if ( !options.restletUrl) {
                    throw error.create({
                        name: 'MISSING_PARAMTER',
                        message: 'restletUrl option is required',
                        notifyOff: true,
                    });
                }
                
                if (typeof options.last_ampersand === 'undefined') {
                    this.last_ampersand = true;
                }
                else {
                    this.last_ampersand = options.last_ampersand;
                }
                
                this.httpMethod = options.httpMethod || "POST";
                this.consumer = options.consumer;
                this.token = options.token;
                this.nonce_length = options.nonce_length || 32;
                this.signature_method = options.signature_method || "HMAC-SHA256";
                this.version = options.version || '1.0';
                this.parameter_separator = options.parameter_separator || ', ';
                this.realm = companyInfo.getValue({fieldId: "companyid"});
                this.urls = {
                    system: "https://" + url.resolveDomain({hostType: url.HostType.APPLICATION}),
                    restlet: "https://" + url.resolveDomain({hostType: url.HostType.RESTLET}),
                    suitetalk: "https://" + url.resolveDomain({hostType: url.HostType.SUITETALK}),
                    forms: "https://" + url.resolveDomain({hostType: url.HostType.FORM}),
                };
                
                this.restletFullUrl = (options.restletUrl.indexOf("https://") == -1 ? urls.system : "") + options.restletUrl;
                
                this.restletUrl = this.restletFullUrl.indexOf("?") > -1 ? this.restletFullUrl.split("?")[0] : "";
                
                this.restletScript = this.restletFullUrl.match(/(?<=script\=)(.*)(?=\&deploy)/);
                this.restletScript = this.restletScript.length ? this.restletScript[0] : null;
                this.restletDeploy = this.restletFullUrl.match(/(?<=deploy\=)(.*)(?=\&)/);
                this.restletDeploy = this.restletDeploy.length ? this.restletDeploy[0] : null;
                
                this.encodedRestletUrl = encodeURIComponent(this.restletUrl);
                
                this.parameters = {
                    deploy: this.restletDeploy,
                    oauth_consumer_key: this.consumer.key,
                    oauth_nonce: makeNonce(),
                    oauth_signature_method: this.signature_method,
                    oauth_timestamp: Math.round(+new Date() / 1000),
                    oauth_token: this.token.key,
                    oauth_version: "1.0",
                    script: this.restletScript,
                };
                
                this.encodedParameterString = '&deploy=' + encodeURIComponent(this.parameters.deploy);
                this.encodedParameterString += '&oauth_consumer_key=' + encodeURIComponent(this.parameters.oauth_consumer_key);
                this.encodedParameterString += '&oauth_nonce=' + encodeURIComponent(this.parameters.oauth_nonce);
                this.encodedParameterString += '&oauth_signature_method=' + encodeURIComponent(this.parameters.oauth_signature_method);
                this.encodedParameterString += '&oauth_timestamp=' + encodeURIComponent(this.parameters.oauth_timestamp);
                this.encodedParameterString += '&oauth_token=' + encodeURIComponent(this.parameters.oauth_token);
                this.encodedParameterString += '&oauth_version=' + encodeURIComponent(this.parameters.oauth_version);
                this.encodedParameterString += '&script=' + encodeURIComponent(this.parameters.script);
                this.encodedParameterString = encodeURIComponent(this.encodedParameterString);
                
                this.baseString = this.httpMethod + "&";
                this.baseString += this.encodedRestletUrl + "&";
                this.baseString += this.encodedParameterString;
                
                this.signatureKey = encodeURIComponent(this.consumer.secret) + "&" + encodeURIComponent(this.consumer.secret);
                
                this.signature = encodeURIComponent(HMAC_SHA256(this.signatureKey,this.baseString, cryptoJS.enc.Base64 ) );
                
                this.Authorization = "";
                this.Authorization += 'OAuth oauth_signature="'+this.signature + '"'+this.parameter_separator;
                this.Authorization += 'oauth_version="'+this.parameters.oauth_version + '"'+this.parameter_separator;
                this.Authorization += 'oauth_nonce="'+this.parameters.oauth_nonce + '"'+this.parameter_separator;
                this.Authorization += 'oauth_signature_method="'+this.parameters.oauth_signature_method + '"'+this.parameter_separator;
                this.Authorization += 'oauth_consumer_key="'+this.parameters.oauth_consumer_key + '"'+this.parameter_separator;
                this.Authorization += 'oauth_token="'+this.parameters.oauth_token + '"'+this.parameter_separator;
                this.Authorization += 'oauth_timestamp="'+this.parameters.oauth_timestamp + '"'+this.parameter_separator;
                this.Authorization += 'realm="'+this.realm + '"';
                
            } catch (e) {
                this.error = {
                    name: e.name,
                    message: e.message,
                    stack: e.stack,
                };
            } finally {
                return this;
            }
        };
```

The Integration record has only "Token Based Authentication" ticked.

Consumer Key/Secret and Token ID/Secret are current, and I've tried setting them multiple times.

It's all running on Server Time (PST) so I don't think Timestamp zone is an issue, but I did try adding +36000 ms (for AEST) but no change.

[image]

Logging generates this data:

```
{
  "auth": {
    "last_ampersand": true,
    "httpMethod": "POST",
    "consumer": {
      "key": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      "secret": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    },
    "token": {
      "key": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      "secret": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    },
    "nonce_length": 32,
    "signature_method": "HMAC-SHA256",
    "version": "1.0",
    "parameter_separator": ", ",
    "realm": "XXXXXX",
    "urls": {
      "system": "https://XXXXXX.app.netsuite.com",
      "restlet": "https://XXXXXX.restlets.api.netsuite.com",
      "suitetalk": "https://XXXXXX.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com",
      "forms": "https://XXXXXX.extforms.netsuite.com"
    },
    "restletFullUrl": "https://XXXXXX.restlets.api.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl?script=576&deploy=1&compid=XXXXXX",
    "restletUrl": "https://XXXXXX.restlets.api.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl",
    "restletScript": "576",
    "restletDeploy": "1",
    "encodedRestletUrl": "https%3A%2F%9999999.restlets.api.netsuite.com%2Fapp%2Fsite%2Fhosting%2Frestlet.nl",
    "parameters": {
      "deploy": "1",
      "oauth_consumer_key": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      "oauth_nonce": "58RInizRvCTdBGuXtugMRPhciQ0OC1xo",
      "oauth_signature_method": "HMAC-SHA256",
      "oauth_timestamp": 1639901494,
      "oauth_token": "b49f1560e07771f8aad11418feae49be6162cf6fbd5d98bff0ae6aac70d4a30f",
      "oauth_version": "1.0",
      "script": "576"
    },
    "encodedParameterString": "%26deploy%3D1%26oauth_consumer_key%3XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX%26oauth_nonce%3D58RInizRvCTdBGuXtugMRPhciQ0OC1xo%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA256%26oauth_timestamp%3D1639901494%26oauth_token%3Db49f1560e07771f8aad11418feae49be6162cf6fbd5d98bff0ae6aac70d4a30f%26oauth_version%3D1.0%26script%3D576",
    "baseString": "POST&https%3A%2F%2F9999999.restlets.api.netsuite.com%2Fapp%2Fsite%2Fhosting%2Frestlet.nl&%26deploy%3D1%26oauth_consumer_key%3DXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX%26oauth_nonce%3D58RInizRvCTdBGuXtugMRPhciQ0OC1xo%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA256%26oauth_timestamp%3D1639901494%26oauth_token%3Db49f1560e07771f8aad11418feae49be6162cf6fbd5d98bff0ae6aac70d4a30f%26oauth_version%3D1.0%26script%3D576",
    "signatureKey": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "signature": "U5iNYAo01jMm3WLdAHUH6R8M7tzooePZ3S0Jc5KQexQ%3D",
    "Authorization": "OAuth oauth_signature=\"U5iNYAo01jMm3WLdAHUH6R8M7tzooePZ3S0Jc5KQexQ%3D\", oauth_version=\"1.0\", oauth_nonce=\"58RInizRvCTdBGuXtugMRPhciQ0OC1xo\", oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA256\", oauth_consumer_key=\"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\", oauth_token=\"b49f1560e07771f8aad11418feae49be6162cf6fbd5d98bff0ae6aac70d4a30f\", oauth_timestamp=\"1639901494\", realm=\"9999999\""
  }
}
```